# stack in c allocating space

Tags: c, stack

I'm trying to implement a stack from my course notes but I get this error when I compile, not sure if I've initialised it correctly? My code segfaults later on when I use the push function.

Update: I now see the double initialisation and the values being assigned to the wrong place.

Here's my code:

```
struct stackelem{
    char i;
    struct stackelem *prev;
};
typedef struct stackelem Elem;

struct thestack{
    Elem *tp;
};
typedef struct thestack Stack;

void InitialiseStack(Stack *s)
{
   Elem *e = malloc(sizeof(*e));   
   s->tp = (Elem *)calloc(1, sizeof(Elem));
   s->tp->prev = NULL;
}

void Push (Stack *s, int n)
{
   Elem *e;

   s->tp = (Elem *)calloc(1, sizeof(Elem));
   s->tp->prev = s->tp;
   s->tp->i = n;
   s->tp = e;
}
```

Comment: `e` *is* uninitialized in `Push()`. Can't you see it?

Comment: I've always found initialising a bit confusing, think my teacher skimmed over it when it was covered. Could you tell me how would I initilise 'e' in the push function please?

Answer (score 0):

```
s->tp = (Elem *)calloc(1, sizeof(Elem));
s->tp->prev = s->tp;
```

You overwrite `tp` and then try to have it point to its old value. This cannot magically happen unless you save it before:

```
Elem *e = s->tp;

s->tp = (Elem *)calloc(1, sizeof(Elem));
if (s->tp)
{
  s->tp->prev = e;
  s->tp->i = n;
}
else
{
  s->tp = e;
}
```

Now the function also won't destroy the stack's state if allocation fails.

Answer (score -1):

These both functions do not make sense.

```
void InitialiseStack(Stack *s)
{
  /* Elem *e = malloc(sizeof(*e));   */
   s->tp = (Elem *)calloc(1, sizeof(Elem));
   s->tp->prev = NULL;
}

void Push (Stack *s, int n)
{
   Elem *e;

   s->tp = (Elem *)calloc(1, sizeof(Elem));
   s->tp->prev = s->tp;
   s->tp->i = n;
   s->tp = e;
}
```

At first in the `InitialiseStack` there is allocated memory

```
s->tp = (Elem *)calloc(1, sizeof(Elem));
```

and then in the function Push the value of pointer `s->tp`  is overwritten.

```
s->tp = (Elem *)calloc(1, sizeof(Elem));
```

As result there is a memory leak. Moreover the value of the pointer is overwritten each time when the function `Push` is called. Also using the uninitialized pointer `e`

```
Elem *e;
```

does not make sense.

All you need is the following

```
void InitialiseStack(Stack *s)
{
   s->tp = NULL;
}
```

and

```
void Push (Stack *s, int n)
{
    Elem *e = malloc( sizeof( Elem ) );

    if ( e != NULL )
    {
        e->i = n;
        e->prev = s->tp;
        s->tp = e;
    } 
}
```